# Define well-order on finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Define a well-order $\le$ in  $P_\text{fin}(\mathbb{N})$ - (it's the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, the natural numbers) that: $ A, B \in P_\text{fin}(N) (A \subseteq B \rightarrow A \le B $)

Could someone solve this for me? I don't have an idea how to do it.

Comment: What is "well-set"? What do you mean by "finite power set"? And solve what, actually?

Comment: Sorry, I meant well-order instead of well-set.

Comment: I'm still unsure what you are asking for.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order

Comment: I think what Wojowu is saying is that the question is still confusing. For example, I see capital $A$ and lower-case $a$ (same with $b$ and $B$).

Comment: I have to find a well-order  for $P_\text{fin}(N)$.

Comment: What I am confused with is: the question is "Could someone solve this for me?", but what do you mean for us to solve?

Comment: It's also not clear what $P_{fin}$ is. How do you define the power set on a collection of sets? Do you mean $\{ A \subset \mathbb{N} \colon A \subset \mathbb{N} \text{ and } A \text{ is finite}\}$?

Comment: I mean, could you help me to define a well order which fulfil the term : $A, B \in P_\text{fin}(N) (A \subseteq B \rightarrow A \le B $

Comment: @par Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: I wonder if some kind of lexicographical order, like in a dictionary, would work...

Comment: I was thinking about taking a subset $A$ and declaring for it a function $F(A) =  \prod_{}^{i \in A} q _{i} $, where $q _{i}$ is i-th prime number. F.x. $q _{5}=11$

Comment: so if $A=\left\{ 3, 5, 7\right\} F(A)=5*11*17=935$, but I am not sure if it's correct?

Comment: Can you prove that this is an order? Can you prove that it is a well-order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f\colon P_{\text{fin}}(\Bbb N)\to \Bbb N$ as $$ f(A):=\sum_{n\in A}2^n$$
and declare $$ A\le B\;:\Leftrightarrow\; f(A)\le f(B).$$
Note that $f$ is injective (in fact, bijective) and so relation defined is a well-order because $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered. Also, if $A$ is the disjoint union of $B$ and $C$ then $f(A)=f(B)+f(C)$, hence $B\subseteq A$ indeed implies $B\le A$, as desired.

Comment: For some reason, this is the first time I've ever seen $:\Leftrightarrow$, despite the fact that it makes so much sense.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this: enumerate the set of all primes $p_i: i = 0,1,2,3,\ldots$. Then define $P: F \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ by $P(F) = \prod_{n \in F} p_n$ (the product is well-defined as we have a finite set), and show this is an injective (by unicity of prime factorisations) and increasing function (a superset has a larger $P$ value). Then $F \le G$ is defined by $P(F) \le P(G)$. This defines a linear order on your set isomorphic to an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, so this will be a well-order for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

For every $k$, the set of $k$-element subsets of $\Bbb N$ is countable, so fix arbitrary well-order $\leq_k$ on it. Now order elements of $P_{fin}(\Bbb N)$ by $A\leq B$ if $|A|<|B|$ or $|A|=|B|=k$ and $A\leq_kB$. I leave it for you to check that this satisfies all the requirements (including the fact that it's a well-order).